# Change color and text of button for a certain period of time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have to change the text and color of a button while the Click Event has occured, but just for a few seconds, then the old values for text and color should appear.

How could this work? Maybe with a async task, which reset the values after the time is elapsed?

The problem is I recognized that the color and the text will be updated only after the click event method has finished.

Comment: Look up storyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently doing lot of research on async and await and currently somewhat addicted to it. So I could not stop myself from answering this one.

**Check out a small sample, below :**

**XAML Code:**

```
<Grid >
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Click Me" Width="88" Height="44" Click="Button1_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind :**

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button1.Background = Brushes.Red;
    Button1.Content = "Clicked State";
    await Task.Delay(8000);
    Button1.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
    Button1.Content = "Click Me";
}
```

> Now let me explain what's happening here :
>
> 1. When the button is clicked, it will enter the async button clicked event handler Button1_Click.
> 2. The button color is changed to red and content changed to "Clicked State".
> 3. Now we can call await Task.Delay(8000), ie the execution of the function is now waiting for the task to complete, which is delayed by
>      8 seconds. The execution returns to the main UI thread and your UI is
>      still responsive.
> 4. After 8 seconds is complete, a free thread from the thread pool will again start executing the rest of the method, after await.
> 5. The button is changed to default background color and content is changed to "Click Me" which was the default content.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for!  Thanks.